# Iterating on Javascript arrays with the "in" keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, iteration

It seems that I don't understand the meaning of the `in` keyword in JavaScript.

Have a look at this code snippet ( http://jsfiddle.net/3LPZq/ ):

```
var x = [1,2]
for(i in x){
    document.write(x[i]);
}
```

When run in the jsfiddle, it prints not only the values contained in the array, but also all of the array object's properties and methods.

When I change it like this ( http://jsfiddle.net/4abmt/ ):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var x = [1,2]
for(i in x){
    document.write(x[i]);
}});
```

it prints only the values 1 and 2.

Why does this happen? Is this caused by jQuery or does the behavior of the `in` keyword depend on whether the document is fully loaded or not?

Comment: In your first example you have Mootools selected as library (which seems to extend the prototype). If you don't select any library, the result is: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/3LPZq/6/. But note that it is bad practice to use `for...in` to iterate over arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the libraries loaded by jsFiddle extend the default prototype of Array, thus it shows these extra functions. jQuery doesn't extend the Array prototype and so you don't see any extra functions.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because of prototype inheritance. An object doesn't only show its' own properties, but all of its' ancestors properties as well.

To find only an object's own properties, use `obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)`.

```
var x = [1,2];
for (var i in x) {
   if (x.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
       document.write(x[i]);
   }
}
```

See MDN Docs on [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Comment: I get it, but then why in the second example it only prints 1 and 2 and none of the other Array properties?